# Proving that a $p$-Sylow subgroup is unique

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $|G|=84$. How can I prove that the $2$-Sylow subgroup is unique?

I know that the $7$-Sylow subgroup in unique, but I don't know how I can use it. So far, I know that $|G|=84=2^2\cdot3\cdot7$, $n \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$ and $n\mid 21$.

Comment: You can't, because it is not necessarily true. There could be $1,3,7$ or $21$ Sylow $2$-subgroups.

Comment: @DerekHolt, we can't within Sylow's framework, but could that be proved/disproved with other tools?

Comment: As I said before, you can't prove it by any tools because it is not true! You can disprove it by giving examples to exhibit the four possibilities.

Comment: You said that it was not *necessarily* true, so letting open the door to the positive case. The counterexample provided in the answer closes indeed the point.

Comment: It is not necessarily true because there exist examples of groups of order 84 with a unique Sylow subgroup, and (again, as I said in my first comment), there exist examples with three, examples with 7, and examples with 21.

Comment: Yea, i forgot to mention that is a true/false question, im sorry. But like hal said, how can i get a conterexemple (Yes, i saw the answer)? Do you have a specific tool for it or you just know?

Comment: Examples with 1, 3, 7 and 21 Sylow 2-subgroups are $C_{84}$, $C_7 \times D_{12}$, $C_3 \times D_{28}$, and $D_{84}$. (I use $D_{n}$ to denote a dihedral group of order $n$.)

Comment: Ok, got it. Im just trying to "show" how this 2-subgroups are. In the answer we have 3 sylow 2-subgroups ins $G=C_7 \times D_6$, how can i know the elements?

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: $G=C_7 \times D_6$, where $D_6$ is the dihedral group of order $12$. The latter group (and hence the group $G$) has $3$ Sylow $2$-subgroups.

Comment: Can you "name" one of these groups?

Comment: What do you mean by naming? Not every group has a name...

Comment: I mean like, what are the elements of the group? How can i check these 3 subgroups?

Comment: Ah ok, for example a presentation is $D_6=\langle a,b: a^6=1=b^2, b^{-1}ab=a^{-1} \rangle$. Please study dihedral groups (see Google), hope this helps.